# Getting image on extension toolbar in open office spreadsheet document in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, openoffice-calc

I have tried to run the project of open office calc, in windows and ubuntu, but images are displayed in windows only, but not ubuntu.
I have used the following piece of code in Addons.xcu found in OXT>registry>data>org>openoffice>Office>Addons.xcu

I have tried to follow as being said in [https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/WritingUNO/AddOns/Images_for_Toolbars_and_Menus][1]

But I am not able to get, how to get images in ubuntu , in open office spreadsheet toolbar.

```
<node oor:name="com.abc.user guide.images" oor:op="replace">
                <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
                    <value>com.abc:User Guide</value>
                </prop>
                <node oor:name="UserDefinedImages">
                    <prop oor:name="ImageSmallURL">     <value>vnd.sun.star.extension://com.ABC/images/help16.png</value><!--Have tried this code but it works in windows, not Ubuntu-->
                        <!--                        <value>%origin%/../../../../../images/help16.png</value> works in case of windows--><!--Have also tried this code,but it works in windows, not Ubuntu-->
                    </prop>
                    <prop oor:name="ImageBigURL">
                        <value/>
                        <!--<value>vnd.sun.star.extension://com.ABC/images/help16.png</value>-->
                    </prop>
                    <prop oor:name="ImageSmallHCURL">
                        <value/>
                    </prop>
                    <prop oor:name="ImageBigHCURL">
                        <value/>
                    </prop>
                </node>
            </node>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing //com.ABC to //com.abc or com.abc or com.ABC  Those xcu files can be a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the difference due to OS, images in drop down menu in the menu tool bar in open office in Ubuntu, are not visible, but rather they are visible in Windows only, when comparison is between Windows and Ubuntu. 
I have tried a project on open office extension in both Windows and Ubuntu.

Even though, if I put icon image on a Jframe, it's not visible in frame, when opened, but rather in task bar of Ubuntu as opposite to in Windows, where image is visible at the top corner in frame as icon, and also in task bar in Windows.

Also compared other menu items in open office where there are no images across the menu button or drop down.

Conclusion :  Difference of OS.

Answer (score 0):

Working Addons.xcu for a Libreoffice 5.0 writer application with a toolbar image and 4 images on the drop-down menu items, this on Linux Mint (Ubuntu).
I hope you can pick the bones out of it, as it took a mammoth amount of editing get it working and the documentation was more a hindrance than a help.
Note: The images should be 26x26 or 16x16. I cannot remember why now.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<oor:component-data oor:name="Addons" oor:package="org.openoffice.Office" xmlns:install="http://openoffice.org/2004/installation" xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <node oor:name="AddonUI">
  <node oor:name="OfficeMenuBarMerging">
   <node oor:name="libreoffice.footswitch" oor:op="replace">
    <node oor:name="S1" oor:op="replace">
     <prop oor:name="MergePoint">
      <value>.uno:ToolsMenu</value>
     </prop>
     <prop oor:name="MergeCommand">
      <value>AddAfter</value>
     </prop>
     <prop oor:name="MergeFallback">
      <value>AddPath</value>
     </prop>
     <node oor:name="MenuItems">
      <node oor:name="M1" oor:op="replace">
       <prop oor:name="Title">
        <value xml:lang="en-GB">Footswitch</value>
        <value xml:lang="en-US">Footswitch</value>
        <value xml:lang="es">Footswitch</value>
        <value xml:lang="de">Footswitch</value>
       </prop>
       <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
         <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument, com.sun.star.text.WebDocument</value>
       </prop>
      <node oor:name="Submenu">
        <node oor:name="M1" oor:op="replace">
         <prop oor:name="Title">
           <value xml:lang="en-GB">Start footswitch</value>
           <value xml:lang="en-US">Start footswitch</value>
           <value xml:lang="es">Iniciar footswitch</value>
           <value xml:lang="de">Starten footswitch</value>
         </prop>
         <prop oor:name="URL">
           <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$footswitch?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
         </prop>
       <prop oor:name="ImageIdentifier" oor:type="xs:string">
        <value>%origin%/icons/footswitch.png</value>
       </prop>
        <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
           <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument, com.sun.star.text.WebDocument</value>
         </prop>
        </node>
       </node>
      <node oor:name="Submenu">
        <node oor:name="M2" oor:op="replace">
         <prop oor:name="Title">
           <value xml:lang="en-GB">List HID Devices</value>
           <value xml:lang="en-US">List HID Devices</value>
           <value xml:lang="es">Lista dispositivos de HID</value>
           <value xml:lang="de">Liste HID Geräte</value>

         </prop>
         <prop oor:name="URL">
           <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$list_hid_devices?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
         </prop>
        <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
           <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument, com.sun.star.text.WebDocument</value>
         </prop>
        </node>
       </node>
      <node oor:name="Submenu">
        <node oor:name="M3" oor:op="replace">
         <prop oor:name="Title">
           <value xml:lang="en-GB">footswitch help</value>
           <value xml:lang="en-US">footswitch help</value>
           <value xml:lang="es">footswitch Ayuda</value>
           <value xml:lang="de">footswitch Hilfe</value>
         </prop>
         <prop oor:name="URL">
           <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$HelpBox?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
         </prop>
        <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
           <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument, com.sun.star.text.WebDocument</value>
         </prop>
        </node>
       </node>
      <node oor:name="Submenu">
        <node oor:name="M4" oor:op="replace">
         <prop oor:name="Title">
           <value xml:lang="en-GB">Edit Config file</value>
           <value xml:lang="en-US">Edit Config file</value>
           <value xml:lang="es">Editar archivo de configuración</value>
           <value xml:lang="de">Bearbeiten Konfigurationsdatei</value>
         </prop>
         <prop oor:name="URL">
           <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$EditConfigurationFile?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
         </prop>
        <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
           <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument, com.sun.star.text.WebDocument</value>
         </prop>
        </node>
       </node>
      </node>
     </node>
    </node>
   </node>
   </node>
<!-- Insert a toolbar image for Start footswitch -->
   <node oor:name="OfficeToolBar">
       <node oor:name="footswitch.OfficeToolBar" oor:op="replace">
           <node oor:name="fstb01" oor:op="replace">
               <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
                   <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$footswitch?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
               </prop>
               <prop oor:name="Title" oor:type="xs:string">
                   <value xml:lang="en">Start footswitch</value>
                   <value xml:lang="es">Iniciar footswitch</value>
                   <value xml:lang="de">Starten footswitch</value>
               </prop>
               <prop oor:name="Target" oor:type="xs:string">
                   <value>_self</value>
               </prop>
               <prop oor:name="Context" oor:type="xs:string">
                   <value>com.sun.star.text.TextDocument, com.sun.star.text.WebDocument</value>
               </prop>
           </node>
     </node>
    </node>

<!-- Assign an image to any reference to the footswitch URL -->
  <node oor:name="Images">
   <node oor:name="libreoffice.footswitch.image1" oor:op="replace">
    <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$footswitch?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
    </prop>
   <node oor:name="UserDefinedImages">
    <prop oor:name="ImageSmallURL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>%origin%/icons/footswitch_26.png</value>
    </prop>
    <prop oor:name="ImageBigURL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>%origin%/icons/footswitch_26.png</value>
    </prop>
   </node>
  </node>
   <node oor:name="libreoffice.footswitch.image2" oor:op="replace">
    <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$EditConfigurationFile?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
    </prop>
   <node oor:name="UserDefinedImages">
    <prop oor:name="ImageSmallURL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>%origin%/icons/config_16.png</value>
    </prop>
   </node>
  </node>
   <node oor:name="libreoffice.footswitch.image3" oor:op="replace">
    <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$HelpBox?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
    </prop>
   <node oor:name="UserDefinedImages">
    <prop oor:name="ImageSmallURL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>%origin%/icons/help-contents_16.png</value>
    </prop>
   </node>
  </node>
   <node oor:name="libreoffice.footswitch.image4" oor:op="replace">
    <prop oor:name="URL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>vnd.sun.star.script:footswitch.oxt|footswitch|footswitch.py$list_hid_devices?language=Python&amp;location=user:uno_packages</value>
    </prop>
   <node oor:name="UserDefinedImages">
    <prop oor:name="ImageSmallURL" oor:type="xs:string">
     <value>%origin%/icons/devices_16.png</value>
    </prop>
   </node>
  </node>
 </node>
 </node>
</oor:component-data>
```